# SQLLDR is getting hanged half way through the data load

Tags: java, oracle, shell, runtime, sql-loader

We are running a peculiar problem wherein the sqlldr is getting hanged half way through while data load process. This sqlldr is being called from Java program dynamically and loads the data in a staging table and subsequently data are merged into the main table from staging table.

We have seen half of the data(approx for 1.7M out of ~2.5M) were loaded and sqlldr is standstill for several hours after that.

We are clueless to the cause of the issue. Would appreciate your insight or any hint to guide us through. Please let me know if you need any further inputs.

**Sqlldr command line used:**

sqlldr  "DB_connection_string" CONTROL="control_path" LOG="log_file" BAD="bad_file"  BINDSIZE=20971520  rows=50000 READSIZE=20971520 ERRORS=9999999

**Oracle Database and SQLLDR version:** 12.1.0.2.0

Regards, 
Vinod Yadav

Comment: Is it feasible to run your sqlldr command from a command prompt instead of inside your Java program? You will then see the output which might help you determine where it's hanging.

Comment: For diagnostics, we need to look at the sql*loader log file.LOG="log_file" and How many entries are in the bad file ? BAD="bad_file"

Comment: @Sam, We ran the sqlldr command on the command prompt yesterday and it ran successfully without any issue. So, we ares still puzzled what is causing it to get hanged when called from Java program. Please advise.

Comment: @Dmitry, we are not getting any "bad_file" either and that is why I am clueless for this issue.

Comment: @VinodYadav if it works from the command line but not in Java, please edit your question to include a MCVE of your Java code.